# Anybody got any C# code to parse robots.txt and evaluate URLS against it

Tags: c#, robots.txt

Short question:

Has anybody got any C# code to parse robots.txt and then evaluate URLS against it so see if they would be excluded or not.

Long question:

I have been creating a sitemap for a new site yet to be released to google. The sitemap has two modes, a user mode (like a traditional sitemap) and an 'admin' mode.

The admin mode will show all possible URLS on the site, including customized entry URLS or URLS for a specific outside partner - such as `example.com/oprah` for anyone who sees our site on Oprah. I want to track published links somewhere other than in an Excel spreadsheet.

I would have to assume that someone might publish the `/oprah` link on their blog or somewhere. We don't actually want this 'mini-oprah site' to be indexed because it would result in non-oprah viewers being able to find the special Oprah offers.

So at the same time I was creating the sitemap I also added URLS such as `/oprah` to be excluded from our `robots.txt` file.

**Then** (and this is the actual question) I thought 'wouldn't it be nice to be able to show on the sitemap whether or not files are indexed and visible to robots'. This would be quite simple - just parse robots.txt and then evaluate a link against it.

However this is a 'bonus feature' and I certainly don't have time to go off and write it (even thought its probably not that complex) - so I was wondering if anyone has already written any code to parse robots.txt ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hate to say that, but just google "C# robots.txt parser" and click the first hit. It's a [CodeProject article about a simple search engine implemented in C# called "Searcharoo"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Searcharoo_4.aspx), and it contains a class Searcharoo.Indexer.RobotsTxt, described as:

> 1. Check for, and if present, download and parse the robots.txt file on the site
> 2. Provide an interface for the Spider to check each Url against the robots.txt rules

Comment: oops. ill admit i didnt search google this time. however ironically this question is now the first match for 'c# robots.txt' :-)  i'll see if i can extract what i need from that. thanks

Comment: I hope you're not stuck in an infinite loop now ;-)

Funny, they even show exactly the Google part of my answer as the preview text. I didn't realize Google has become so fast by now even for non-news sites, very interesting.

Comment: Am I falling into the loop? :)

Answer (score 3):

I like the code and tests in http://code.google.com/p/robotstxt/ would recommend it as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of self promoting, but since I needed a similar parser and couldn't find anything I was happy with, I created my own:

http://nrobots.codeplex.com/

I'd love any feedback